# How to leave an open if statement when using require()?

Tags: php

I'm trying to decide on a good design template and I'd like to do something like this:

```
<?php require 'variables_file.php';
      require 'template_header_member.php'; ?>

My HTML Content

<?php require 'template_footer_member.php'; ?>
```

The problem is, I would like an if statement to span from the header template to the footer template and when I require template_header missing a "}" I get an "Unexpected end of file" error. Are there any better ways of going about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot leave the block open because each PHP file has to be complete on its own.

You should probably look into [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) - it will allow you to capture the HTML content and then process it in your footer depending on your logic, without touching the main PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot span a single statement across multiple files.

An idea would be to set a constant in the header file and for you to check the value of that constant (or if it was set) in each of the files that you plan to require/include after the header.